# how many friends do you get to meet there?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

Is this correct way to ask a question to a person who went to party function, there he wanted to meet his friends?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

In a slight variation of your question, the present tense is perfectly acceptable:

> "I went to the new club downtown again last night."
>   "Oh! I've heard it's a popular place. How many people **do** you get to meet there?"
>   "It's always busy. You get to meet a lot. You should check it out yourself."

Here, the present can be used to describe an *ongoing* situation, even if something specific took place in the past.

---

But while it's fine to use the present tense to ask such a question in general, in your *specific* question, where you mention **friends**, the past tense is more appropriate:

> How many friends (of yours) **did** you get to meet there?

This is because while you might be expected to always meet a lot of *people* at the place being discussed, you might not be expected to always meet a lot of *friends* there. Also, the context doesn't sound like friends in general but friends of the person who went.

Answer (score 0):

For past simple questions use **did** instead of **do**

How many friends did you meet there?